# NetBeans can't use classes created using another IDE

Tags: java, netbeans

I created a new project in NetBeans, and I wanted to use some utility class I created in Eclipse. I just copied my utility classes and pasted it them in NetBeans and saved the changes. Now I can't instantiate or use the classes I copied to NetBeans.

Did I miss any step?

Comment: this makes no sense. Netbeans and eclipse don't have "their own java syntax". If the code is correct, and you copy pasted them on the right location, there should be no problem whatsoever.

Comment: Did you paste thing into the same project or a different project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your source path in Netbeans does not include the directory where you have copied the class source from Eclipse.

- right click on the Netbeans project and select "Properties" from the context menu
- in categorie "Sources" you can define the "Source Package Folders"

Check if the directory which contains your utility classes is listed there.